# "Dirac operators have finite-dimensional kernels"

Tags: trace

I am currently reading the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628). The definition of the index of a Dirac operator uses the fact that the kernel is finite-dimensional. Unfortunately the proof is rather short:

> Proposition $3.37$. If $D$ is a Dirac operator on a compact manifold $M$, then the kernel of $D$ is finite-dimensional.
>
> Proof: The operator $D^2$ has a finite-dimensional kernel, and hence so does the
> Dirac operator $D$.

Furthermore I found another hint on page $4$ of the book:

> Smooth kernels are trace-class, from which we see that the
> kernel of a Dirac operator is finite-dimensional,

In summary, I believe that the reasoning is as follows: By definition $D^2$ is a generalized Laplacian, and all generalized Laplacians (on a compact manifold) have a finite-dimensional kernel, because they admit a heat kernel and kernels are trace class.

It is not clear to me why the existence of a heat kernel implies a finite-dim. kernel, can someone elaborate please?